# ARM Template concat with multiline

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm almost sure last time I was playing with ARM templates there was some trick to make code tidy and concat() with multiple lines. Yes, I know I could use

```
"myvar": "[concat(
  'abc',
  'def
  )]"
```

**if** I'm deploying with cli/powershell, but I won't control the tools of the template's users, so they'll very likely just copy-paste into web console.

Any idea? Besides having a custom function to join multi-line text encoded as array:

```
"variables": {
    "splitStr": [
      "first line",
      "second line",
      "third line"
    ],
    "output": "[custom.join(variables('splitStr'))]"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "namespace": "custom",
      "members": {
        "join": {
          "parameters": [
            {
            "type": "array",
            "name": "splitStr"
            }
          ],
          "output": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[replace(replace(replace(string(parameters('splitStr')), '[\"', ''), '\"]', ''), '\",\"', '\\n')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

We're talking about a working sample code pushing hundred-ish lines of configuration text into a deployed VM, so text readability is important.

Comment: Curious to see what your expected input is. If people are running from the portal how will they provide the input? As a single string? As an array of lines?

Comment: The input format is to be decided by me. The main point would be to make it readeable in the code. So for the last example it would be an array of lines:

Comment: I was trying to in-line a user-data script in an ARM template in a readable way and this was very useful - however I had to change the `'\\n'` to `'\n'` to get the multi-line contents rendered properly in a file.